# AWS Fargate container fails to start with error CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, aws-fargate

Looking for advice on what I'm missing. Fargate container fails to start with the error `CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daem`

EDIT: Longer error response

```
Status reason   CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get https://{account}.dkr.ecr.{region}.amazonaws.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I created a non-default VPC with CIDR block `50.10.0.0/16`. In the VPC, I have 3 public subnets with an internet gateway attached and subnet route table with `0.0.0.0/0` as a record. (I am able to launch an EC2 instance in these subnets, it received a public IP, and I can connect to it via SSH.) My VPC also has `DNS hostname` and `DNS resolution` enabled.

On the Task definition side, I created a Fargate task using `network mode = awsvpc`, requires `FARGATE compatibility`, and is trying to pull a container from a private ECR that looks like `{account}.dkr.ecr.{region}.amazonaws.com/{imagename}:latest`. Launching the container I use platform `v1.3.0` and enable `AUTO-ASSIGN PUBLIC IP`. In my security group, I allow `All Traffic` both inbound and outbound on `0.0.0.0/0`. For my Role, I am using one that has the following policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:*",
                "secretsmanager:*",
                "ssm:*",
                "logs:*",
                "sqs:*",
                "s3:*",
                "ecr:*",
                "ecs:*",
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and trusted entities for `ecs.amazonaws.com` and `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`.

Watching the Task as it goes from `PENDING` to `STOPPED`, I can see that the ENI receives a public IP. Always, I get the same error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...I had my DHCP options set configured incorrectly.